# How can I be able to make arima order i.e. (p,d,q) same for my data set of same therapeutic class but different brands?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

First of all, I would like to give you a brief introduction of mine. I am a student of MS in Management Sciences with major in Supply Chain Management.

For my thesis, I have selected topic "Demand Forecasting Of Pharmaceutical Industry".I am using `R` package for demand forecasting and used arima model for forecasting. I am just able to get data of 20 quarters of different pharmaceutical companies of Pakistan who deal with the same therapeutic class to cure for disease. At first, I applied cubic spline method to transform my quarterly data to monthly than check normality by shapiro and ad test to check normality after transforming quarterly data into monthly and then run auto.arima  command in `R`. After running `auto.arima` function on different data set of same therapeutic class I landed to no man's land as I got different values of $(p,d,q)$ of same therapeutic class manufactured by different companies.

Kindly suggest me some measure, how can i be able to make my parameters/orders value same for a therapeutic class irrespective of the company?
Attached herewith raw data its transformation and arima result.

[raw data and its working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BypHL3VCdO81T2pRM3preldLUDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1)Why would you expect to get the same pdq?? 2)Why are you transforming to monthly?

Comment: Dear @TomReilly,
Answer 1) As I have shared in my data sheet that I have taken data of drugs manufactured by different companies; if I would be able to get same value of pdq it will be easier for me to design algorithm. Thus forecaster easily be able to get the forecasted value.
Ans 2) Because I have limited access to data i.e.I am only able to get 20 quarter actual sales data from the sources that's why i need to interpolate data.

Comment: Hi R.Siddiqui.... 1)If you have no theory as to why the pdq should be the same and you are somehow trying to FORCE your algorithm on the data then I think you have things backwards.  The data is not a slave to you. 2)Why interpolate?  It adds nothing to the process.  Analyze the data at a quarterly level.  You could interpolate to a weekly level, but why???  It makes no sense.

Comment: Dear @TomReilly; I am not trying to force algorithm on the data. Let's start this way i have 5 companies A B C D E and all manufactures a drug of 250mg tablet that is used for curing cancer disease but with different names when I run arima model and got following results like:
A (3,1,0)
B (2,0,4)
C (5,1,2)
D (2,1,2)
E (1,1,2)
Now, kindly guide me how can i interpret these results and draw conclusion as there is no harmony. How can i be able to make any algorithm that is fit for all?

Comment: The reason to interpolate quarterly data into monthly is to make training set of data and test set of data and according to many researchers for ARIMA model minimum 30 observation would produced better result. I request you @TomReilly kindly go through once the file I have attached for reference above
Thanks,

Comment: You could convert your models to a pure right hand side equation to compare them (see http://www.ualr.edu/jcpickett/Lecture7.htm).   The minimum is not  any kind of hard and fast rule, but the fact remaines that you aren't going to gain any more power by making more #'s.  Use the monthly.

Comment: To be very true, I am unable to understand to convert my model to right hand side equation; link you @TomReilly you attached explains only the treatment of autoregressive models not for moving average models. I will be highly obliged if you can make me understand in a simple way.
Thanks,